# Sorting table using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, sorting

I have this table in which I read the `tbody` contents from a JSON API and now I need to make it sortable by columns and using only javascript and no Jquery.

Any help would be appreciated

i have found this [code](https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/zYGOrzK) which is exactly what i want, but i don't know how to refer to tbodies from my api

```js
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
myRequest.onload = function () {
  var myData = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
  dataTable(myData);
};
myRequest.send();

function dataTable(data) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var temp = '';
    data.forEach((u) => {
      temp += '<tr>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.userId + '</td>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.id + '</td>';
      temp += '<td>' + u.title + '</td>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.completed + '</td></tr>';
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Completion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried the basic approach such as shown in [these examples](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp)?

Comment: yes but it's too slow and doesn't work very well with big numbers

Comment: Have you tried to use datatable? You may refer the following URL:  https://datatables.net/

Comment: Sortable as in draggable or sorted automatically by javascript?

Comment: i also shouldn't use any jquery or libraries, only vanilla javascript

Comment: sortable by clicking the theads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myData, asc = {'userId':true, 'id':true, 'title':true, 'completed':true};
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
myRequest.onload = function () {
  myData = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
  dataTable(myData);
};
myRequest.send();
function sortTable(key){
    myData.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(asc[key]){
            return a[key] > b[key]? 1:-1;
        }
        else{
            return a[key] > b[key]? -1:1;;
        }  
    });
    asc[key] = !asc[key];
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '';
    dataTable(myData);
}
function dataTable(data) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var temp = '';
    data.forEach((u) => {
      temp += '<tr>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.userId + '</td>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.id + '</td>';
      temp += '<td>' + u.title + '</td>';
      temp += "<td style='text-align: center'>" + u.completed + '</td></tr>';
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sortTable('userId');">UserID</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('id');">ID</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('title');">Title</th>
            <th onclick="sortTable('completed');">Completion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome, first thanks everyone, but this is actually working great, but i also need the switch from asc to desc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick class I made.
You first load your data with dt.load(), then when someone clicks one of the headers, you can add an event that does:

```js
elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    prop = e.target.textContent.trim();
    dt.sort(prop);
    dt.render();
})
```

```js
class DataTable{

    load(arr){
        if(arr) this.data = arr;
    }

    sort(prop){
        this.data.sort((a, b) => a[prop] - b[prop]);
    }

    render(selector="#data"){
        if(data.length){
            html = data.map(u => {
                return [
                    "<tr>",
                    `<td style='text-align: center'>${u.userId}</td>`,
                    `<td style='text-align: center'>${u.id}</td>`,
                    `<td>${u.title}</td>`,
                    `<td style='text-align: center'>${u.completed}</td></tr>`
                ].join("");
            }).join("");
            document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Important - are you wanting to be able to sort multiple columns at the same time or just one column at a time?

Initialize myData outside of onload first. You'll want to be able to access those results outside of onload to sort them. The actual sort function JS offers is a pretty confusing but it's really the only way to go about vanilla JS array sorting.

```
function sortData(col, asc = true) {
    //JS sort function
    myData = myData.sort((first, second) => {
        //sort logic

        if (first[col] == second[col]) {
                return 0;
        }

        if (asc) {
            if (first[col] > second[col]) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (first[col] > second[col]) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    });

    //Re-Create table
    dataTable(myData);
}
```

EDIT:

I added in sort logic, but it's definitely possible I messed up. I can't actually test this right now and I haven't touched the sort function in years.

Comment: can i also trouble you with the reverse sort from asc to desc?